# lsyncd - How to include specific directories and exclude rest of all directories

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, backup, wildcards, synchronization

I want to include some of the directories in lsyncd process and exclude rest of all directory.

I have so many directories in a `multisource` directory. I want to include only `temp` and `temp1` directory and exclude rest of all directories in lsyncd.

I try using below code in `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua` file,

```
settings {
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}
sync {
        default.rsyncssh,
        source = "/var/www/html/multisource",
        host="user@<ip_address>",
        targetdir = "/var/www/html/multisource",
        delay     = 5,
        rsync = {
                perms = true,
                owner = true,
                group = true,
                --include = {"/temp", "/temp1"},
                --exclude = {"/*"}
        }
}
```

Does have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are replicating files and folders that are present at `/root/hive/data` folder but there lies a folder `/root/hive/data/logs` that you don't want to replicate, then:

You need to create a file `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.exclude` and specify the folders/files inside this file that you wish to ignore for replication, in our case `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.exclude` should contain:

```
logs
```

Make sure that you give relative path.

The `sync{}` directive in `/etc/lsyncd.conf` should be as follows:

```
sync {
default.rsync,
source="/root/hive/data",
target="***.***.**.***:/root/hive/data",
excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd.exclude",

rsync = {
compress = true,
acls = true,
verbose = true,
owner = true,
group = true,
perms = true,
rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use the `lsyncd.exlude` list under `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.exclude`

```
settings {
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}
sync {
        default.rsyncssh,
        source = "/var/www/html/multisource",
        host="user@<ip_address>",
        targetdir = "/var/www/html/multisource",
        delay     = 5,
        excludeFrom = "/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.exclude",
        rsync = {
                perms = true,
                owner = true,
                group = true,
                --include = {"/temp", "/temp1"},
                --exclude = {"/*"}
        }
}
```